# Rendering XML response on Grails problem

Tags: xml, grails, render, xmlslurper

I'm having problems rendering an XML file parsed via XMLSlurper to an XML variable.
Below is my code.

def userFile =new File("test.xml")
def xml= new XmlSlurper().parse(userFile)

render xml

The problem is I cannot see the xml being rendered into my flex app.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to render the xml file you can say:

```
    def xmlFile = new File("test.xml")
    response.contentType = "text/xml"
    response.outputStream << xmlFile.text
```

And there's no need for the slurper at all